# In ABCL how do I break from a runaway function without killing LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, break, control-c, abcl

In ABCL, during development I sometimes get runaway functions. I want to be able to stop execution and return to top level LISP without killing the LISP/JVM process (in my emacs shell) and losing my current LISP environment.

I've tried various control keys (e.g., Control-C, Control-D,...) but at best end up killing LISP or the JVM.

`;;; How to stop this function and return to LISP interactive
;;; without killing lisp...?
(defun runaway ()
  (let ((result nil))
    (dotimes (count 10 result)
      (sleep 2)
      (print count))))`

C-c C-cTerminate batch job (Y/N)? n
n

Process inferior-lisp exited abnormally with code 130

Comment: NB: I just saw your question because I rarely look at the abcl tag; you would have better exposure if you add the "common-lisp" tag too (or lisp)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Emacs with Slime instead, because Slime does not kill the process but interrupt the thread and enters the debugger if you press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>.

You should probably add an executable script `abcl.sh` somewhere in your PATH, as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec java -jar .../abcl/abcl-bin-1.5.0/abcl.jar
```

You have to replace `...` with your own path to `abcl.jar`.

Then, from Emacs, you should be able to start it.

Do <kbd>C-u M-x slime</kbd> to force the `slime` command to prompt for an executable, and give `abcl.sh` to it. It should start the process and connect to it using the Slime protocol.